# Using Lookahead positive to identify Single character words

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am working on a Data cleaning task for a NLP project, and my goal is to count occurrences of single word characters in the text.
For instance,

```
text=' b ant'
```

I just need the answer as `['b']`. I used the positive lookahead feature to identify it;

```
re.findall('\s(?=[a-z]\s)',text)
```

The way I understand it is; it will first match a whitespace, then enter the lookahead part in the regex pattern (without moving in the string, anchored at the first whitespace), and look for a letter immediately followed by white space in the string.

But the answer I am getting is;`[' ']`

Can I get some help on how to get the desired output as `['b']`. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Depending on you requirements you may simply want to match the regex `r'\b[A-Za-z]\b'`. In the string `'a is to b as c, the third letter, is to d (e we can forget) or f.'`, it would match `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'d'`, `'e'`, and `'f'`, even only two of these words (`'b'` and `'d'`) are surrounded by spaces. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/rP2xk8/1/). Hyphenated words and words containing apostrophes are problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookaheads are non-consuming patterns, all the texts matched by lookaheads are not part of the overall match value.

The `\s(?=[a-z]\s)` pattern matches and puts into match memory buffer a single whitespace char that is immediately followed with an ASCII lowercase letter and whitespace.

You seem to want

```
m = re.search(r'\s([^\W\d_])\s', text)
# Or, m = re.search(r'\s([A-Za-z])\s', text)
if m:
     print(m.group(1))
```

To get all occurrences:

```
re.findall(r'\s([^\W\d_])(?=\s)', text)
re.findall(r'\s([A-Za-z])(?=\s)', text)
```

Or, if you also need to match at the start/end of string:

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[^\W\d_](?!\S)', text)
re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[A-Za-z](?!\S)', text)
```

Here, `\s([^\W\d_])\s` matches

- `\s` - a whitespace char
- `([^\W\d_])` - Capturing group 1: any Unicode letter (`[A-Za-z]` matches any ASCII letter
- `\s` - a whitespace char
- `(?<!\S)` - matches a location not immediately preceded with a non-whitespace char
- `(?!\S)` - matches a location not immediately followed with a non-whitespace char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j3mPJ4/1).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex to recognize words. `.split` will split the sentence into words for you:

```py
In [1]: text = ' b ant'       

In [2]: [word for word in text.split() if len(word) == 1]    
Out[2]: ['b']
```